# .htaccess rewrite url - convert from nice URL back to GET parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite url from this:

```
https://www.domain.com/blog/category/sub-category-name
```

to this:

```
https://www.domain.com/blog/category/?category=sub-category-name
```

also it must work with others parameters like:

```
https://www.domain.com/blog/category/sub-category-name?param=value => https://www.domain.com/blog/category/?category=sub-category-name&param=value
```

or

```
https://www.domain.com/blog/category/sub-category-name#hash => https://www.domain.com/blog/category/?category=sub-category-name#hash
```

I don't understand this rewrite syntax so any advice is valuable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /blog/$1/?$1=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Additional Query perameters are automatically appended to the target path by QSA flag.